# Error while pulling mysql database in local mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to pull heroku mysql database into my local mysql database but it gives me some error.

I have posted the issue on github. [Here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/457) is the issue which i have posted on github. I also post the log of error.

please help me to solve out this problem.

Is there any other way to get heroku database into my local database..?

I am also trying to fetch data via chunksize but it fetch only 60 to 70% data after that it gives the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely MySQL has reached `net_read_timeout` during operation - it defaults to 30 seconds (it happens with heroku).

Add in your MySQL configuration file:

```
net_read_timeout = 300
net_write_timeout = 300
```

restart MySQL and try again.

Comment: I am working on mac mini. So from where i can made this changes...??

Comment: depends on MySQL version, but usually it's /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Heroku don't directly supply MySQL services - so which MySQL Add-on are you using?

Comment: @NeilMiddleton I am use taps add-on to pull mysql database.

Comment: But what MySQL DB are using on Heroku - the default is Postgres

Answer (score 3):

You can use command prompt for importing the DB, otherwise size constraint is there.

Use mysql command for the same. 
Refer: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-import-command/

Comment: i m fetching the data from heroku server and heroku dosen't provide any .sql database file.