# How to restart mysql server using a parameter

Tags: mysql

I want to enter the following parameter into mysql:

```
--net_read_timeout=100
```

How would I stop and restart the mysql server with this parameter? Normally I just do:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo service mysql start
```

When would I enter to change this parameter?

Comment: Did you check if you cannot add this param to mysql.conf ?

Comment: Similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468120/error-while-pulling-mysql-database-in-local-mysql-database